# Django Forms: error displaying

Tags: django, forms

I have the following code:

```
            {% if form.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                  {{ form.errors }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
```

This produced the following:

[image: error picture]

I would like to remove the bullet points and not include the __ all __ part.

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks, Alan.

Incase it may be helpful the clean part of the form is as follows:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data # individual field's clean methods have already been called
    team1 = cleaned_data.get("team1")
    team2 = cleaned_data.get("team2")
    if team1 == team2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You picked the same team!")

    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for error in form.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
            {{ error }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I believe that should work. What output do you get with that?